# Jquery UI auto complete in navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an autocomplete input in the header. The UI-widget-content is not being displayed just to the bottom of the input field. It is covered up by the navbar.

```
<div class="form-inline header-form">
        <div class="ui-widget">
          <input id="ServiceType" type="search" name="ServiceType" class="ui-autocomplete form-control" placeholder="Service type" >  
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should add whole relevant HTML and CSS code so we can help you. ideally would be to make a Snippet or JSFiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code its working for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#ServiceType" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      <li>
       <div class="form-inline header-form">
        <div class="ui-widget">
          <input id="ServiceType" type="search" name="ServiceType" class="ui-autocomplete form-control" placeholder="Service type" >  
        </div>
       </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Inverted Navbar</h3>
  <p>An inverted navbar is black instead of gray.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Check this [codpen](http://codepen.io/eraditya123/pen/VjVGEL)